# Why is the covariance of white noise not finite and not a Kronecker delta?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, covariance, dirac-delta, correlation

Suppose we have a Gaussian white noise $f(t)$. Then the covariance $\langle f(t)f(t')\rangle = c\times\delta(t - t')$ for some $c > 0$.

However, since $f(t)$ is a Gaussian random variable (with variance $c$, say).
Then $f(t)^2$ should be a chi-squared variable with one degree of freedom, and should have mean $c$.

As the noise at different times are independent of each other, we should rather have

$\langle f(t)f(t')\rangle = \begin{cases}
 c&\text{if }\, t = t^\prime\\
 0&\text{if }\, t \neq t^\prime\\
\end{cases}
=c\times\delta_{(t-t^\prime),0}
$ (which is a Kronecker delta, not a Dirac delta).

If we think physically, suppose we have many copies noise generators and we measure $f(t)^2$ at the same time in all of them and take the average. Clearly, it will be finite and approximately equal to $c$.

Why do we have the Dirac delta function in the correlation instead of the Kronecker delta function? Am I missing something?

Please note that this is not a duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1154940/dont-understand-dirac-delta-function-for-white-noise) because I am asking about why the covariance (or correlation) of the noise is not finite. Sure, the Fourier transform of the spectral density implies it is a Dirac delta function, but I don't understand how it happens physically.

Comment: In short, the quantity $<f(t)^2>$, which is the mean of many finite quantities, should not diverge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$<f(t)^2>$ is infinite!  Its frequency spectrum is flat.  The auto-correlation and the frequency spectrum are Fourier transforms of each other.

Comment: Is not $f(t)$ finite? Then $f(t)^2$ will also be finite and its average will also be finite. Unless we mean sum (and not average) by the $<.>$ notation?

Comment: $f(t)$ is a random variable with mean $=0$, but the second moment is infinite.

Comment: A side question, if the second moment is infinite, then how does one simulate it? Do they take a very large number as the standard deviation?

Comment: I have never tried to simulate white noise, so I don't know how.